# Convergence in normed spaces 1/sup

Tags: convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

$f_n \in C([0,1])$ is a sequence of functions. Why is the implication

$f_n$ converges to $f \in C([0,1])$ with respect to $||·||_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $f_n$ converges to $f$ with respect to $||·||_\infty$ wrong?

Well, i tried to do: For $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N$ so that for $n>N$ there is $||f_n-f||_1<\varepsilon$ to conclude the falseness, but i didn't find a solution.

So how to prove that this implication is not true?

Comment: If $f_n(t)=t^n$, what are $||f_n||_1$ and $||f_n||_\infty$?

Comment: To prove that the implication does not hold for all sequences $\{f_n\}$ and functions $f$, you need to find an example of such a sequence $\{f_n\}$ and a function $f$ such that the implication does not hold.  David Ullrich's example is a perfect one.

Comment: Well, so it's $||f_n||_1 =\int_{0}^{1}|t^n|dt$ 

and 

$||f_n||_\infty= \ \sup_{t\in [0,1]}|t^n|$

But why does this implication not hold in this case?

Comment: Anyone knows why $f_n(t)=t^n$ doesn't hold the implication? It is $|f_n(t)-f(t)|<\varepsilon$ so how to conclude?